# Can anyone help me in choosing the suitable statistical analysis for my research?

Tags: measurement

I have conducted an experimental research last week. The research topic is about Influence of Voice Assistants on Satisfaction, Attitude and Purchase Behaviour.

I had 46 participation in total and 23 participant for each control and experiment group. I add my conceptual framework in attachment. Each Factors has 4 items in the questionnaire. Questions were designed with 7 Point-Likert scale from 1 to 7 (ordinal).

Therefore which tests do i need to run to get best results? What is the best test for comparing control and experiment groups? T-Test? KS-Test? Or what is the best test to understand the correlations between variables? Factor Analysis? Regression Analysis?

Which steps do i need to follow first?

I'm a bit confused and I don't know where to start and which steps to follow? I'd appreciate your helps. Thanks.

[image]